# How to run my Python module in Visual Studio Code in interactive mode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I need something similar to "-i" option of original Python interpreter, but to be able to watch variables state, use code completion and other nice IDE features as well.

I've installed appropriate Python extension for Visual Studio Code, but so far by pressing F5 it just runs module once and exit without letting me do anything, pretty much in the same way as C/C++ Visual Studio debugger work. I can use break points, but I want to use power of Python interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`stopOnEntry`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_stoponentry) which starts the debugger when the program stops, but there's no equivalent `stopOnExit`. If you would like that then please file a feature request at  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/discussions/16082